# Android: how to get system rights officialy

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to Turn ON/OFF Mobile data programmatically. For this issue I need to use MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission.
As we know in latest Android versions it's not possible for non-rooted phones **unless** the app has system rights.

I know that exists some workaround how to sign the app as system app. But as I understand it's not possible to publish such app at the Play Store.

My question is the next - is it possible to get system rights officially? If it is possible which way I have to go to get them?

Comment: "is it possible to get system rights officially?" -- build your own custom ROM. Then, sign your app with the signing key used to sign the ROM. Or, sign a distribution deal with a device manufacturer, where they will sign your app with their ROM signing key(s).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not appropriate to create a custom disc, when I need one application to get the system right. Whereas distribution deal could be acceptable decision. But I don't understand one thing - why I should talk with device manufacturer, not with OS creator (Google)? And which manufacturer it should be? Is it means that if I make a deal with Samsung then my app will work on Samsung devices and will not works on HTC devices (for example)?

Answer (score 1):

THe only way to get them is a rooted device, or to build the device image yourself.  The idea of system permissions is that only apps which are trusted by the creator of the system (the OEM) can request them.  You can also get them by rooting the device, because of how they're granted (its based on the directory the app is installed in, which can be accessed if you have root).  But there is no way to do it without root or without creating your own OS image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Rooting the device isn't acceptable way in my case. I understand the idea of system permissions. Actually I'm talking exactly about the question - what should I do to became a trusted app? And who should trust me? Device manufacturer (ROM creator)? Does it mean that I should talk with each manufacturer if I want to run my app on their devices?

Comment: The OEM (or whoever else installs the system image).  Basically, if you won't root you'd have to be a pre-installed app.  So not just getting the OEMs to make you a trusted app, but have them have your app installed when the user buys it.  They'll do that for a price or if you're extremely popular (like facebook popular), but it isn't cheap.

Answer (score 0):

`MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is a system-only permission so there's no way to get that permission unless you root your phone.